# Android Build Target cant be selected in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I followed these tutorials to set up a Hello World Android app. But when I create a new java project I can't select a build target. It just says no targets available in the target selection box. I have confirmed that I am not having the UI issue described here (http://blog.rowancrane.com/2009/12/27/eclipse-new-android-project-cant-select-build-type-target), I actually have a message in the box saying there are no targets instead of an empty box. I also am using 1920x1080 res.

I'm guessing that eclipse is just not aware of my Android Targets? I installed them in the android SDK manager and see them listed under installed packages in the Android SDK manager (1.1, 1.6, ..., 2.2)

http://fyi.oreilly.com/2009/02/setting-up-your-android-develo.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Any suggestions on how I can create the project and get started?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are missing the file "project.properties" in your project folder

Answer (score 19):

In **Eclipse**, do this:

**Window** -> **Preferences** -> (In the field "*SDK Location*", add your path to your Android folder, e.g. "*C:\android-sdk-windows*" and then click "*Apply*" -> **OK**.

Now you should be able to select a target.

Answer (score 6):

For MAC users,

In Eclipse, do this:

Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android -> (In the field "SDK Location", add your path to your Android folder, e.g. "/Users/user/Projects/Android/android-sdk-mac_x86" and then click "Apply" -> OK.

Now you should be able to select a target.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that at least one version of Android SDK is installed. To check this, go to window > Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a Java Project, instead create an Android Project. In the setup steps you can define a build target. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just upgrade android sdk ools to rev. 22.6.2 n problem will be solved,at least my problem is solved